# get-log-events returns only a few results of many

Tags: python, aws-cli, boto

I am logging to CloudWatch from a python lambda. In the AWS console I can see several hundred log entries, but if I try to use get-log-events from either a Python Boto call, or through the AWS CLI I only ever seem to get the most recent 2 entries.

I use the following AWS CLI command:

```
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name hall-ac --log-stream-name sensors
```

I've tried changing it to set time limits, read from head or tail, or change the limit, but nothing seems to have any effect. I thought that the above command should read up to 10000 entries, but it doesn't do that. Is there a way I can enable debugging to see why only some logs are being returned?

I can use the next-token parameter to retrieve a few more log entries, but it will take hundreds of calls to read every log entry if it only delivers 2 each time.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 limits in `get-log-events`:
1MB of data
10000 log events

So, whichever limit you hit first. I guess that you have bigger logs and thus you're hitting the 1MB limit

You can see more details in the [documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.0.34/reference/logs/get-log-events.html)

Comment: Each log entry is about 100 characters and I'm only getting 2 of them, so I'm nowhere near either of those limits.

Answer (score 1):

adding the flag `--start-from-head` helped me out. I was using the nextToken to manage the pagination.

As per the docs:
"If you are using nextToken in this operation, you must specify true for startFromHead ."

Comment: I wasn't using `nextToken`, but adding that flag solved it for me too